# Swift range beacons in multiple regions

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I'm trying to build an app for rang beacons in multiple regions. I found the tutorial https://mentormate.com/blog/beacon-ranging-ios/ and I did it, but I don't know how to update beacons.

Comment: What do you mean "update beacons"?

Comment: I mean when I launch the app, it display beacons near me. But if I power off a beacon or power on another one, the app doesn't update list. Because does it only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial show show to do range multiple beacon regions in the following lines:

```
// 4
let beaconRegions = [CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "F7826DA6-4FA2-4E98-8024-BC5B71E0893E")!, identifier: "Kontakt"),
                     CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")!, identifier: "Estimote")]

// 5
beaconRegions.forEach(manager!.startRangingBeaconsInRegion)
```

Note that `beaconRegions` is an array with two region definitions.  You can add as many region definitions as you like to this array to range multiple regions.

The code is designed to update the display with any new beacons detected:

```
beacons.forEach { beacon in
    if let index = beaconList.indexOf({ $0.1.proximityUUID.UUIDString == beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString && $0.1.major == beacon.major && $0.1.minor == beacon.minor }) {
        beaconList[index] = (region, beacon)
    } else {
        beaconList.append((region, beacon))
    }
}

// 3
tableView.reloadData()
```

The `beaconList.append((region, beacon))` line is supposed to do this.  If it is not working, check that you have that line and the following `tableView.reloadData()` set up properly in your source.

Also check that your new beacon matches one of the region definitions.

It does not appear that the code has any mechanism for removing beacons that disappeared from the list.